# Zap Proxy - script to modify headers automatically

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, proxy, ruby, zap

Hello just wondering if someone already wrote a script for Zap to modify headers automatically with out me having to do it on each response/request..
example.
modify response from 3xx or 4xx to 2xx to bypass some misconfigure sites.
If I can't find any I will try to write my own, just trying not to reinvent the wheel. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered here: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/4022

For simple replacement theres the Replacer add-on: https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-extensions/wiki/HelpAddonsReplacerReplacer and for more complicated situations there are httpsender scripts: https://github.com/zaproxy/community-scripts/tree/master/httpsender

Answer (score 2):

If you're set on using a script you could build an HttpSender script that does something like:

```
function sendingRequest(msg, initiator, helper) {
    // Nothing to do here
}

function responseReceived(msg, initiator, helper) {
     msg.setResponseHeader(msg.getResponseHeader().toString().replace('404','200'))
}
```